# Sock Merchant problem in javascript using splice not working

Tags: javascript

My following solution worked for 6 test cases out of 9 test cases and i couldn't wrap my head around on why is it not working for the following test case. Note: I used splice instead of the sorting first methodology. Thanks in advance.

The problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sock-merchant/problem

```
function sockMerchant(n, ar) {
    var i=0,j=1;
    var count = 0;
        while(i<=ar.length-1 && ar.length>1){

            if (ar[i]==ar[j]){
                ar.splice(i,1);
                ar.splice(j,1);
                count++;
                i=0;
                j=i+1;
            }
            else{
            if(j>=ar.length-1){
                i++;
                j=i+1;
            }else{
                j++;
            }
            }
        }
return count;
}
```

Successful test case:
10 20 20 10 10 30 50 10 20

Output: 3

Failed test case:
4 5 5 5 6 6 4 1 4 4 3 6 6 3 6 1 4 5 5 5

Output(expected):9

Comment: What is the problem statement and what is this function suppose to do??

Comment: I have added the link to the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your index 'j' is always larger than index 'i', you should not splice 'i' first. Removing the lower element will offset index of all following array elements.

Try change

```js
ar.splice(i,1);
ar.splice(j,1);
```

to

```js
ar.splice(j,1); // remove higher element first
ar.splice(i,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized you could also sort your array, then check for duplicates through a for loop

```
function sockMerchant(n, ar) {
    let count = 0
    const arr = ar.sort()
    for (let i=0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
            i++
            count++
        }
    }
    return count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also solve it with an object to check map existing socks like so:

```
function sockMerchant(n, ar) {
// Write your code here
let socks = {};
let pairs = 0;
for (let sock of ar){
    socks[sock] = socks[sock] + 1 || 1;
}
for(let key in socks){
    pairs +=Math.floor(socks[key]/2)
}
return pairs;
```

}